# Logstash cannot index data to Elasticsearch [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use logstash to index data into Elasticsearch. At first, it indexes successfully but after a few moments, when I tail `tailf /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log`, it gives me this error:

```
retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];"})
Retrying individual bulk actions that failed or were rejected by the previous bulk request. {:count=>1}
retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];"})
Retrying individual bulk actions that failed or were rejected by the previous bulk request. {:count=>1}
retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];"})
Retrying individual bulk actions that failed or were rejected by the previous bulk request. {:count=>1}
```

My logstash output config:

```
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}-%{shift}"
        manage_template => false
    }
```

My elasticsearch config:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
cluster.name: elasticsearch
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: machine
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9301"]
path.repo: ["/home/repository"]

node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
node.attr.box_type: warm
node.name: hot_es01
node.attr.machine: ${HOSTNAME}

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT
http.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

**what possibilities can cause this?**
I can think of read_only indexes, ES out of disk. But I checked and they are not. 
Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What is the disk size of the elasticsearch node and how much space is available? There are a couple of watermark configurations that can make elasticsearch stop to write data even if you have space. Per default with 85% used it stops alocating shards, with 90% used it tries to move shards away from the node and with 95% it sets the index as read only. [shard allocation documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html)

Comment: @leandrojmp I don't think disk size is the problem. I run ES via docker and mount it here /u01/elastic5:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw . And only 14% of u01 is used. /dev/sdb1      1008G  131G  827G  14% /u01

Comment: What do you have in Elasticsearch logs? I would suggest to enable the debug logs and see if you can get more information.